# How can I add an ampersand for a value in a ASP.net/C# app config file value

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I've got a C# program with values in a config file.  What I want is to store ampersands for an url value like...

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="myurl" value="http://www.myurl.com?&cid=&sid="/>
</appSettings>
```

But I get errors building my site.  The ampersand is not allowed.  I've tried various forms of escaping the ampersands to no avail.  Anyone know of the correct form to do this?  All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 478, accepted):

Use "`&amp;`" instead of "&".

Comment: I seriously thought I had tried this.  I think I missed the trailing ";" at the end.  Anyways it does works so thanks for the feedback Eric.

Comment: This works, but I have to put a string.Replace("&amp;","&") whereever I access this setting, or else the browser won't properly detect it when you click on the link :/

Comment: Well... that's pretty disappointing. I mean, that the ConfigurationManager does not automatically unescape these &xyl; characters when getting them from the config file.

Comment: @Efrain not sure what DLeh is talking about exactly, but unescape definitely works fine. Just tested this with standard `appSettings` as well as a custom `NameValueCollection` section: ampersand is unescaped properly on both.

Answer (score 30):

Have you tried this?

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="myurl" value="http://www.myurl.com?&amp;cid=&amp;sid="/>
<appSettings>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be able to use the HTML escape character (&). They can be found at http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: This link isn't displaying any article at the moment.

Comment: Link is still dead.

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted answer here is technically correct, there seems to be some confusion amongst users based on the comments.  When working with a ViewBag in a .cshtml file, you must use `@Html.Raw` otherwise your data, after being unescaped by the ConfigurationManager, will become re-escaped once again.  Use `Html.Raw()` to prevent this from occurring.