# C#: Caused error :having a string variable which its value contains &?

Tags: c#, string

**EDIT:** I have edited my post...

Working on a project (c#), I have a string (password) within an XML file (app.config) which it value contains '&' character. Suppose it some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
     <appSettings>
        <add key="MainConnectionString" value="Data Source=MyDataSource;InitialCatalog=MyInitialCatalog;User ID=MyUserID;Password=ynhub&59=k31!890" />
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

But compiler shows me an error and a squiggly blue line appears under 59 indicates that 'character 5 hexadecimal value is illegal in an XML name'

How can I remove this error?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: I would be more interested in seeing the compiler error as having '&' in a string should be perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you missing the quote characters, like: string foo = some text & stuff; instead of string foo = "some text & stuff";?

Comment: It does not get any error.
string g;
g = "Hi & how are u.";
textBox1.Text = g;

Comment: Or are you trying to concatenate strings "VB style"? Dim s = "this " & "is a " & "string.". If so use + instead.

Comment: Sani Huttunen , u looks right. It seems that problem will be of concatenate strings.

Comment: Eh, don't concatinate strings with + or &, use String.Concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML starts special characters with an & character, i.e. the famous &amp;, &lt; (<) and &gt; (>).

For this reason you cannot use & in your XML without converting it to &amp;. For example even in HTML links it's not allowed (but still common) to write:

```
<a href="foo.php?foo=bar&bar=baz">
```

It has to be written as:

```
<a href="foo.php?foo=bar&amp;bar=baz">
```

Noone is doing it but HTML & XML specify it that way and especially XML is very strict about it.

Answer (score 2):

[Use "`&amp;`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376135/how-can-i-add-an-ampersand-for-a-value-in-a-asp-net-c-app-config-file-value).

Answer (score 0):

The & you're thinking of isn't part of the string - it's part of your source code. Carefully read the code, paying careful attention to the position of any quote marks...