# my locally hosted asp.net C# site in IIS server is giving error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

my locally hosted asp.net C# site in IIS server is giving error 
"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."
....Please help
and thanks in advance

Comment: plese what is the raw error data you are recieving??

Answer (score 0):

It could be a mal-formed Web.Config file. Use your browser to open the Web.Config file. If it's mal-formed it won't open.

Similar question and answer here:

[The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for)

Answer (score 0):

this might help ... [asp.net iis7.5 http 500.19 error](http://forums.asp.net/t/1836605.aspx/1?IIS%207%205%20HTTP%20Error%20500%2019%20Internal%20Server%20Error)