# Asp.Net Core tag in web.config causes failure

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core application which works on one machine but not on another.

The problem is that the application fails to load, because the IIS does not recognize the following

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

The result is that when I click on the IIS authentication configuration, I get an error. If I remove the `aspNetCore` tag I can view the authentication settings, but then the application doesn't actually start.

Before you start giving advice about not using `web.config` for .NET Core, remember that it works on my other machine. Also, I need to use Windows Security and ASP.NET Impersonation.

Both machines are running Windows 10 Pro, and I have checked the following

- IIS features installed: identical
- WAS and W3SVC: both started and running under Local System
- Application Pool: both have .Net 4.0 CLR, classic mode
- Folder and file security: identical
- Binary compare of the application and all dlls: identical

I don't normally work with IIS and .NET, so I'm quite puzzled that my application breaks on one of two seemingly identical installations. I have run out of things to check. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the complete `web.config`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: a447f5e7-6aee-4d26-bef4-c7111a88c409-->
```

Comment: Are the .NET Core server components installed?

Comment: What does ".NET Core server components" mean? I have "ASP.Net 4.7" enabled on the IIS on both machines.

Comment: You need to download the relevant "Windows Server Hosting (x86/x64)" from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime , having the standard .NET installed is not enough.

Comment: I would assume that the runtime would be installed along with Visual Studio (Express) - as running the app in Express works (when I disable impersonation). I installed it anyway, and it didn't help :(

Comment: VS uses IIS Express so doesn't need it. For .NET Core you generally should be using an Unmanaged application pool.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek did you get the solution. I am facing same issue

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I did, but I think I was missing the ".Net Core 2.0.x - Windows Server Hosting" component, which has to be installed. You should be able to find a newer version here https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.0.6 (pick Windows Installer).

Comment: If you have this issue with a 32-bit Asp.Net Core app [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53562972/2292053)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue and it was because the machine
was missing the NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. If this is not installed then IIS cannot recognize the `aspNetCore` section in `web.config`

You can install the bundle from below location.

[NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

Comment: This was exactly the problem for me, although the blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rohithrajan/2018/03/13/500-19-error-or-502-5-error-when-hosting-asp-net-core-2-application-inside-iis/ actually links to an older version.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle claims to be the latest.

Comment: Also, a wrong version of Hosting Bundle will give this error.

Comment: Yes! Had Hosting Bundle **5.0.7** installed, got strange error message. Installed Hosting Bundle **5.0.9** (the newest as of writing this) and error went away.