# How to Fix “HTTP Error 403.14 – Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory”

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. This error occurs when I have MVC 4 Application running hosted on IIS 7.5.

I am using Windows 7, I have .Net frame work 4.5 and Visual studio 2012 is installed.
I have tried with

```
  <modules> 
     ... 
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> 
  </modules>
```

Then it shows the error 
" **The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**  "
How to resolve this ? Please help me As early as possible

Comment: Hai,any one can help me???

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. Now the error is like this. Please help me

Comment: If you still have the 500.19 error, there is a lot of good information for that, at this SO post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for/18896551#18896551   Note that a few of the issues near the bottom -- answers that got *few* votes -- are things I've seen in real life... so if the top answers don't help *you*, keep going down the list.

Comment: P.S.  To help others, consider posting your resolution to the title question:  How did *you* resolve the 403.14 error?