# How to deploy ASP.Net MVC 5 to IIS 8 Windows Server 2012?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, iis-8

I developed an application in ASP.Net MVC 5 with database SQL Server 2012
now I want to deploy it in Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8

I followed this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

but when I run my application in browser it gives error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error  The requested page can not
>   be access because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

I am new in this area please if you could explain in details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for

Comment: Please include the error description you got in your browser

Comment: Are there any other asp.net sites already installed on this server or is this the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish it first selecting your project on Visual studio . After that you need to create the site on IIS. In some case you can find diffiult on mapping your db for that you need to add the permission on the db server.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if are installed the asp.net role in your server.

I hope this link can help you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831475.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you have the latest .Net packages installed. I had a MVC5 app targeting 4.5.2 that would refuse to start.