# Can't access login page web config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

This my **web.config** file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <connectionString>
    <add 
      name="ColMAX" 
      connectionString="data  Source=SHANTHA;Initial Catalog=Billing_Test;Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionString>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms 
        defaultUrl="~Default/.aspx" 
        loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
        slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I can't access the login page. This is the error I get:

> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module     :  IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    : Unknown
>
> Handler      :Not yet determined
>
> Error Code       :0x80070032
>
> Config Error   :  The configuration section 'compilation' cannot be
>   read because it is missing a section declaration Config File
>   \?\c:\users\sudath\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Colombo\Colombo\web.config

I just start my project. Can anyone solve this ?

Comment: There should be more details on your error like in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for  could you put them here?

Comment: Seems like the Correct Frame Work for Application Pool is not installed.  can you check the Application Pool's .net frameWork.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Web.config as below.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionString>
   <add name="ColMAX" connectionString="data  Source=SHANTHA;Initial Catalog=Billing_Test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionString>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms defaultUrl="~Default/.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"   slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
   </authentication>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Registering Application Pool for .Net frameWork 4.5**

Navigate to

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

Open the command window here (Ctrl + Shift + RightClick ) -> Open command Window here.

Type the below commad in the command window.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Hope this will fix your peoblem.

Comment: Compilation tag and httpRuntime tag  is in wrong place and moved to System.Web