# IIS Server & ASP.Net Core - 500.19 with error code 0x8007000d on httpplatformhandler tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

I am getting the following error when I try to launch my ASP.Net Core App using IIS Server v7.5 ... I published the website (File System option in Visual Studio) to a specific directory successfully. It launches fine from approot/web.cmd file. But when I try to hook it up to IIS Server and point it to the wwwroot folder, I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> - Detailed Error Information
> - Module  IIS Web Core
> - Notification    Unknown
> - Handler Not yet determined
> - Error Code  0x8007000d
> - Config Error
> - Config File \?\D:\WebDevelopment\UAT\creativeNamePROD\wwwroot\web.config
> - Requested URL   http://10.2.177.226:59/
> - Physical Path
> - Logon Method    Not yet determined
> - Logon User  Not yet determined
> - Failed Request Tracing Log Directory

Below are two different web.config files I tried any neither one worked. When I try to get into Configuration Editor within IIS, I get an unclear error as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="64768" maxUrlLength="65536" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="64768" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Web.config #2 -gets the same error

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: same error for me, but just a hint, on my windows 10 machine it works fine, but same exact files, deployed on Win Server 2013 R2, results in above error

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle?  This is needed for IIS to work as a reverse proxy for the .net core libraries. You'll find the link in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis  I had the same problem before installing this on my dev machine.

Comment: To future readers. This question is valid for old ASP.NET Core releases (ASP.NET 5 RC or older builds), where there was no ASP.NET Core module, but only HTTPPlatformHandler (for `httpPlatform` tag). No one should see such a `web.config` any more.

Answer (score 101):

I was getting this error. I fixed this error by **installing the .NET Core Windows Server *Hosting bundle*** (vs the *Runtime Bundle*), as described in [instructions like this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle).

> **Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle**
>
> Install the *.NET Core Hosting Bundle* on the hosting system. The bundle installs the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module creates the reverse proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server. If the system doesn't have an Internet connection, obtain and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable before installing the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

As @Patrick says you can download the bundle installables from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows).

After installing that Module, my app served  (i.e. no 500 error).

I see @Jørgen made this comment on OP already, so he gets credit.

**EDIT** Please confirm you install the *Hosting bundle* vs the *Runtime Bundle* per comment  by @MDave

> Did you install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle? This is needed for IIS to work as a reverse proxy for the .net core libraries.  You'll find the link in this article: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis I had the same problem before installing this on my dev machine. – Jørgen Tvedt Mar 28 at 6:31

Comment: Get the install files from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: FYI, for any literal programmers - I think what was meant in the second sentence is, "I installed..." as opposed to, "I did not install..."

Comment: Fantastic! Life saver!! This is true even when we had .net core 2.1 hosting installed but only the 2.2 sdk but not the .net core 2.2 hosting. Thank you!!

Comment: In my case I had installed the _Runtime Bundle_ instead of the _Hosting Bundle_.  After installing the Hosting Bundle it worked.  Wasn't aware they were two different things.

Comment: aha - thanks! I had assumed that because I had visual studio and asp.net core SDK installed, I would have everything I needed to run it but no, you need the hosting bundle as well

Answer (score 9):

The only solution worked for me was to install 2 more items from Microsoft dot net core library:

> https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.6-windows-x64-asp.net-core-runtime-installer

and

> https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.0.6-windows-server-hosting-installer

Comment: Hosting bundle contains the actual runtime, so usually people only need to install the Hosting bundle.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, delete file: `project.lock.json` and run `dotnet restore`, `restart visual studio`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this same problem when running in Visual Studio Community 2017 v. 15.7.1.

Had to install the latest dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-rc1-008673-win-x64.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-rc1-windows-x64-installer

Comment: You must have hit another issue. The SDK does not contain the server bundle, and so merely installing the SDK won't resolve "Error Code 0x8007000d". What you hit should be another error code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with one .NET 6.0 site, but not another, so I knew the hosting pack was installed and functioning correctly.

The issue turned out to be that the broken site had some elements pertaining the URL Rewrite module, but the module wasn't installed.

Problem solved by either removing those elements, or installing the URL Rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked and then after few weeks it stopped working with config error 500.19. After scratching my head for few hours. I downloaded the hosting bundle from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0 and repaired my already installed version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: uninstalling the .NET Core Hosting Bundle and then reinstalling it fixed this issue for me.**

There are many different situation that can produce this error. In my case I was using IIS 10 on Windows and .NET 6 trying to run and ASPNET Core Web App.  The problem was that I had apparently installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle before I had installed IIS.  I was setting up a new machine and had a boatload of dev software to install.

At the time I was experiencing the issue I couldn't remember the order I had installed things but one SO post suggested that if I had installed them in the wrong order I could rerun the .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer and select the repair option.  So I did that and the error persisted.

So sadly, for a long time I figured installing in the wrong order wasn't my issue.  *But....it was.*

Turns out repair didn't fix the problem for me, but uninstalling the .NET Core Hosting Bundle and then reinstalling it did.