# .Net Framework Core service returns 500.19

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-core

I have a fairly simple .Net Framework Core project.

[image]

The Controller folder contains controllers, as you may expect. 
The Swagger folder contains our swagger config.
The app.config file contains:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

-The appsettings.json contains our swagger base path for the project.
-The BuildAndDeploy.ps1 script builds the service and then drops the artifacts into a folder where IIS can find them.
-The commands.json file contains the command to run swagger
-The nlog.config is as you would expect
-The Program file contains:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```

The web.config contains:

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

The service seems to deploy correctly in the sense that the service builds and the files are copied into the correct location.

In IIS, under the default website, is the application created for my service.

There is a custom app pool set up specifically for this service and the identity is set up to be my user account.

Here comes the issue. When I browse to my service (or any other service on my machine for that matter) I get this error:

[image]

I have visited the following posts and have followed its instructions:

[How do I resolve "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" on IIS7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929131/how-do-i-resolve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-on-iis7-0)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/-http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

There were others but I cant seem to find them right now.

I have installed the URL rewrite module, I have checked windows features and made sure that the suggested features are installed. I've read through at least 5 more articles. I have re-added web.config and even recreated my project in the hopes that the issue would magically be resolved.

None of this has worked!

Here is the explanation of the error Im getting:

[image]

I am at a total loss. If anyone has any idea of what else I can try or something I may have missed please let me know.

Comment: .net core doe not use web.config

Comment: Let me first say that as I mentioned, it is still a .NetFramework project. As you can see from the error it is seeing a malformed web.config. All of our services contain the same files and work on our other dev boxes. Only difference is that my lappy is new while the others have been in use and configured to use the apps for awhile. This tells me that there is a setting or something related that is missing.

Comment: The ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework wizard in VS2017 does not generate `web.config` by default. Whether it targets .NET Core or .NET Framework, it runs different from ASP.NET 4.x, so you need to install ASP.NET Core module on IIS (which is the cause of 500.19).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Server & ASP.Net Core - page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948865/iis-server-asp-net-core-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configur)