# Edit Web.config file

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following webconfig file produced by visual studio 2017 on a .net core application

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SportsStore.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

<!--ProjectGuid: 5795049b-4d7e-4559-9010-f9134df11849-->
```

Although the publish succeed I get the following on the web page

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module
   IIS Web Core
Notification
  BeginRequest
Handler
  Not yet determined
Error Code
  0x8007000d
Config Error

Config File
   \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sportstore\web.config
Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/sportstore
Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sportstore
Logon Method
  Not yet determined
Logon User
 Not yet determined
Config Source:
 -1: 
  0:
```

Because I have already work only on apache and the build in IIS express of visual studio I do not know where to start from. Internet has plethora of info and I tried many things but nothing.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x You simply forgot to install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Server & ASP.Net Core - page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948865/iis-server-asp-net-core-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configur)