# Web App IIS Error HTTP 500.19

Tags: http, iis, web, host

I want to host my web app on IIS. But I get an Error all the time. HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
Code: 0x8007000d
It says that config file is bad (web.config in my case)
What is wrong with it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ServerApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b5218e98-989b-4275-96f0-53c91a5f235a-->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Server & ASP.Net Core - page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948865/iis-server-asp-net-core-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configur)

Answer (score 0):

It was an ASP.NET Core app, so after installing .NET Core Windows Server Hosting everything works just fine

Comment: hi i have the same issue as  you , isn't .NET Core Windows Server Hosting a part of .NET Sdk ?

Comment: @A.HADDAD I dont know about .net core 3.0, but it wasnt a part of sdk when I used 2.2