# Issues on configuring IIS for mvc asp .net 3.1 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have problems with hosting web app on IIS. In next photos you will see my configuration files that I change and errors that I have when try start app on browser.

web.config:

```
    <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
                arguments=".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TaskTracker.Frontend.dll" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 
                hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[hosts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sbS0.png)

[applicationHost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6oCI.png)

[applicationHost part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EgPp.png)

[Error when I try to see authentication of app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqVaR.png)

I was setup permissions on app folder in properties-security of foler.
When I try to consume app through browser, error was:
[server error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn9rY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS Server & ASP.Net Core - 500.19 with error code 0x8007000d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948865/iis-server-asp-net-core-500-19-with-error-code-0x8007000d)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your web.config file configuration, I suggest you reinstall IIS and ASP.Net Core module to restore the configuration files.