# asp.net MVC, IIS - HTTP 404.0, 403.14

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

This is my first project in asp.net MVC. Build works in Visual Studio. When I publish website to server I get this two errors:

> HTTP 403.14 – Forbidden

I get this one if I visit server based on ip. It says I can probably fix it by setting default webpage. I know where to do it in IIS, but I dont know what to put there. I have only one controller *Home*, which has *Product* view. So I tried to set *Home/Product*, but nothing happend.

> HTTP 404.0 – Not Found

This is happens when I try to access to controller, x.x.x.x/Home/Product for example.

Project runs on Windows Server 2012 + IIS. In IIS I use *Default Web Site*. I added permisson to users from outside by this command *IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool*.

In Visual Studio I make build through *Build > Build web* to local drive and move all files to server.

Comment: Here's a list of things to check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2011/04/22/test-your-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds/

Comment: Is this MVC core App? if you can provide project structure and home controller code and config files it will be more easy to tell you whats wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll only get guesses based on above post - e.g. "forbidden" - what were you requesting? A "forbidden" file (type)? While `404` is "not found" in the context of MVC, things like `route` matters (so it's not "obvious")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it by this advice: [stackoverflow.com/a/9239936/3246527](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/9239936/3246527). Thank you all.

I probably followed some bad tutorial which missed this part.

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

1. Check the app pool identity has permissions to the root folder of
   the site.
2. Check that there is a default page configured in the root folder in
   the site and that the default page is listed in the default
   documents list for the site.

> 403 Forbidden The request was valid, but the server is refusing
>   action. The user might not have the necessary permissions for a
>   resource.
>
> 404 Not Found The requested resource could not be found but may be
>   available in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are
>   permissible.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

> 1. Is Directory Browsing turns to Enabled?
> 2. Is Folder Project Directory User has Permitted?
> 3. Check application pool framework(IIS) VS Project Framework.
> 4. Always check in application pool > right click created website > advance settings > General tab (32bit or 64bit)