# CORS in ASP.Net MVC with SignalR causes "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc, cors, signalr

I use `SignalR (v2.4.0)` in an `ASP.NET MVC` project with `Angular 8` and encounter *"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:/demo.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=' from origin 'http://localhost:20700' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."* error while debugging (also similar error in PROD stage). I have tried to apply fixes on [Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method), but most of them not worked or not a global fix. Instead of applying Controller stage, I would prefer a fix globally in `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs` (I also tried web.config fixes, but never worked). So, is there any global fix for this problem?

**Update:** Here is my configuration to fix the problem:

***Startup.cs:***

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Demo.Web.UI.App_Start.Startup))]
namespace Demo.Web.UI.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

***web.config:***

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:20700"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>    

</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

To work for me I had this in my startup.cs...

In "ConfigureServices" method:

```cs
services.AddCors(options => {
         options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
             builder.WithOrigins("https://www.websitename.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
         });
});
```

In the "Configure" method I had this:

```cs
app.UseCors(builder => {
    builder.WithOrigins("https://www.websitename.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
});
```

Then in my controller I had this attribute:

```cs
[EnableCors]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
  ...
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your help. BUT, I use ASP.NET MVC and there is no `AddCors` method. Could you please post whole Startup.cs with using libraries? Additionally, I would prefer a global fix instead of adding `[EnableCors("AllowOrigin")]` notation to each Controller. Any idea?

Comment: You can add the CORS settings in web.config. That's usually how I get it done. https://gist.github.com/Jalalhejazi/5653347

Comment: Modified code above to make it default global policy instead of specifically named policy

Comment: @Svend I had already tried as indicated on Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ASP.Net MVC - simplest possible method issue. But I get *"The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."* error and then remove Access-Control-Allow-Methods line. But in this case still encounter "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:/demo.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionData=' from origin 'http://localhost:20700' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error. Any idea?

Comment: @RobMcCabe But ASP.NET MVC and there is no AddCors method. Any idea?

Comment: @RobMcCabe I added an Update.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing

Comment: @RobMcCabe Any help please? The problem still persists although I have tried many different approach :(

Comment: Sorry I've only implemented this in ASP.net Core - it should be straight forward enough.  This article seems to offer some help for your version of .net Framework ASP.net:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @hexadecimal If you're seeing that msg you have something funky on the IIS server (probably). Did you google what that error msg lead to? For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for

Answer (score 1):

On your startup.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
```

...

```cs
//Branch the pipeline for requests that start with "/signalr"
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on Your web.config file
change
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:20700"
to
add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"