# Trying to run .net core api which uses swagger from local IIS

Tags: iis, .net-core, swagger

I created a .Net core web api application and using swagger .I am trying to create a profile for the application to run it on IIS while run the application from visual studio 2019.

Application folder has full permissions and the app pool /website, both are running under service account which has full admin rights.

I am trying to configure the application to use https to run on a specific port 443.Not sure if i have to make any code changes so that application runs on specific port

If i try to run the application using IIS express with the url https://localhost:portnumber/TestApi/swagger.It works beautifully

If i try to use the profile that is configured for IIS to run the application with the url "https://localhost/TestApi/swagger, then its throwing the error.

Below is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44342" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have my start up.cs file as follows

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //Configuration = configuration;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
              .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            ConfigSettingLayoutRenderer.DefaultConfiguration = Configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info()
                {
                    Title = "Test APIs",
                    Description = "REST APIs",
                    Version = "v1"
                })
            );

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
            });
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("TestApi/swagger");
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            });
        }
    }
```

and my launchsettings.json as below

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/TestApi",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57086/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "PmDashBoard.Api": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost/TestApi",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost/TestApi"
    }
  }
}
```

I have .Net core hosting bundle is installed on my machine and latest version of VS2019 installed. I am trying Ctrl + F5 to run the application from VS2019 and getting the below error

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:

Module
   IIS Web Core

Notification
   BeginRequest

Handler
   Not yet determined

Error Code
   0x80070003

Config Error
   Cannot read configuration file

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for

Comment: I gave permissions to the folder and the apppool and website are running under service account which has admin rights. I am trying to run the application with https on a specific port 443... I am not sure if i am doing anything wrong in the configuraiton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for)