# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core 6 application with Angular 12 on IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis

I used the publish feature of Visual Studio to publish my project in a folder. After that I added a Website to IIS on my web server and bound it to the folder where I put all the generated files.

The publish folder looks like this:

[image: Publish folder]

The IIS structure looks like this:

[image: IIS]

When I start the website, it just loads and loads without achieving any result.

Comment: Open Network tab of your browser's developer tools, and see what requests/responses are.

Answer (score 2):

you could follow the below steps to deploy the angular asp.net core app to the iis:

1. Download and Install asp.net core 6 runtimes and hosting bundles

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

[image]

2. Open the project in a visual studio.
3. Right-click on the project and choose publish:

[image]

4. In target select folder option:

[image]

5. Set the folder path where you want to publish the site.-> click Finish
6. Now open iis click on the server name and select add website
7. While adding a website give any name, select your publish folder and set the port number -> click ok

[image]

8. To browse the site select site name and click browse from the action pane.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex said, you should check the browser's develop tool to see what the server replied.

And also I suggest you could try to open the browser to type in the `https://youriissitedomain:port/api/controllername` to call your web api to see what server has returned to make sure your asp.net core server-side has works or not.

If it doesn't work, I suggest you could firstly check you have install the right .net core runtime for your server from this [article](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Then I suggest you could make sure your IIS web site's application pool has the right permission to access the folder. For more details about how to check ,you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67362475/7609093).