# Deployment on IIS (local) of ASP.NET Core 8 and Angular (v17.2.1) application made with Visual Studio 2022 template

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, iis, deployment

I've been developing applications using ASP.NET Core and Angular from versions 3.1 and 9.1.0 respectively, using the provided templates of Visual Studio (2022), Up to .NET 6 and Angular 14 I had no issues so far. Everything was straightforward regarding the development and deployment of the application.

However when I decided to create a new application using the latest versions of .NET Core and Angular (8 LTS & 17.1.2) The template was changed by Microsoft. now the new template features 2 projects inside the solution and I'm trying to figure out how I can deploy the application properly on a dedicated local IIS server.

From the [documentation provided my Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0) and from some extensive search I've looked upon the internet I did not manage to find specific instructions on how to properly deploy the application on IIS.

I've installed the Hosting bundle on the IIS server (v8.0.2) and I've tried to deploy the sample app created by the template just to see if it will work, with no luck. All I get is a blank page with a 404 error (as shown below),

[image]

while on the development environment I can see the demo app running fine, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

The new template does not use a Startup.cs file, also in Angular since v17 all the components are standalone (not sure if this piece of information is useful on the subject, but I have to mention it)

Has anyone used the template as it is shown in the link provided above to create and deploy an ASP.NET 8 with Angular application ? I could really use some help here as this is getting frustrating.

What I need is detailed instructions on how to deploy an application created with the template stated above and what settings should I use on the IIS server.

Please let me know If any further information is needed.
Thank you in advance

I've tried publishing the app to a local folder and also to the IIS server directly, from the publishing options of Visual Studio 2022.

I expected the template demo app to work as it worked in the development environment.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I would check in IIS Manager.  Click on the host, then click "View Sites".   It should show you the path and binding.  Check to confirm that's where you are publishing to.

Comment: what you'll see in the sites section is where your backend should be published... inside of that there should be a special folder called "wwwroot" which should contain your ng build output.  If you see that this folder does not contain index.html, and your js/css files, you should include your program.cs file in your question. (you might need to add something like: app.UseStaticFiles...)

Comment: @browsermator , Indeed inside the wwwroot folder there is a browser folder that contains the output of the ng build. However what I wish to know is the proper settings for the IIS site, IF they differ from the previous versions of NET (and the respective templates) and where they differ, in order to deploy the application properly

Comment: This link should help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938159/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938159/13336642).

Comment: @samwu Thank you, but the issue is the template update  on VS2022. I've deployed an app on NET 6 & Angular 14 with no issues. When the template changed, from microsoft however, then the struggle began. I'll look into it further and will let you know when I come up with something. Thank you in advance