# Cannot deploy a Web API ASP.NET Core on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis

I already read/watch multiple tutorials about deploying an API on ISS.

I did it step by step, multiple times but I still got the same issue....

> 'the requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid'

[image: Error :]

I didn't change ANYTHING in the code.

I'm using a folder publish method.

Can you help me please? I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong :/

I just want my app running like a simple API...

Comment: It seems the permission issue. Could you copy the publish files to `D: `OR `E:` drive for testing, it's a qucik way to verify if it is a permission.

Comment: This is happen when site have configuration issue, check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/iis-500-19-with-0x80070005-the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-rel)!

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 features are already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

random text to fill stackoverflow requirements.

Comment: Thanks man its working now... its was that simple... Where do you find the info please ?

Comment: I had the exact same problem this morning with a react deploy and asked Bing chat