# Is it possible to have an ampersand sign in an appSettings key? error: web.config value is not defined

Tags: asp.net, appsettings

I have the following appSettings section

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Foo" value="http://foo.bar.com/?app=xxx&FormName=yyy" />
</appSettings>
```

But the IDE is giving me two errors:

1. Error   25  Entity 'FormName' not defined.
2. Error   26  Expecting ';'.

It seems the **&** is causing a problem.  I'd like to not have to splt the values up into seperate keys.  Is there an elegant way around this issue?

Comment: You just need to remember that a `.config` file is XML and all XML rules still apply...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an ampersand for a value in a ASP.net/C# app config file value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376135/how-can-i-add-an-ampersand-for-a-value-in-a-asp-net-c-app-config-file-value)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You just need to use XML encoding here I believe - so `&` becomes `&amp;`

Answer (score 12):

```
Try &amp;

<appSettings>
  <add key="Foo" value="http://foo.bar.com/?app=xxx&amp;FormName=yyy" />
</appSettings>
```