# C# Configuration File assignment error

Tags: c#, config

Just starting out working with C# to develop some small utility programs for the Windows platform, normally working in Linux. Been interesting to say the least. However,  I have ran into a small problem within AppConfig that I am not sure how to correct.  This program will be used at a number of locations, so want to hold connection information out in a config file. In other programs I have created, this has not been a problem.

However, this time I have ran into something with the URL that is causing me grief. The URL has to have an = sign in it. (Not my choice). 
    http://somehost/webservice.php?auth=3767etr&entity=bob&update=1

If I define it as a string in the program, compiles and runs with no problem. But if I put it into the AppConfig I end up with errors about items(auth,entity,update) not being defined.

```
<add key="HostName" value="http://somehost/webservice.php?auth=3767etr&entity=bob&update=1"/>.
```

I would think that the quotation marks would "shield" things but guess not. I thought about defining items in program with NULL value. Is that the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an ampersand for a value in a ASP.net/C# app config file value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376135/how-can-i-add-an-ampersand-for-a-value-in-a-asp-net-c-app-config-file-value)

Comment: The problem is not the equals sign, but the ampersand

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probablly the & and not the =. Try using & as described in this post.
[How can I add an ampersand for a value in a ASP.net/C# app config file value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376135/how-can-i-add-an-ampersand-for-a-value-in-a-asp-net-c-app-config-file-value)