# How to handle ampersand in URL string with more parameters as a value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uri

I'm trying to send ampersand as a value of one of the url parameter but without any success.

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("WebForm.aspx?P1=&P2=&P3="));
```

E.g. "WebForm.aspx?P1=John&P2=Smith&P3=Del&Company" returns John Smith Del. So everything after ampersand as a value in url is trimmed.

Is there any trick how to handle this issue.

Note: The url is feeded by parameters from somewhere else.

Comment: User [Server.URLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx) before sending values in URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the `&` with `&amp;`?

[How can I add an ampersand for a value in a ASP.net/C# app config file value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376135/how-can-i-add-an-ampersand-for-a-value-in-a-asp-net-c-app-config-file-value)

Comment: Url is taking dynamically parameters from somewhere else. How can I handle that.

Comment: @martinkabe You should edit your question and add that detail.